# Return Largest Numbers in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am struggling with this task in FreeCodeCamp, I don't know where is wrong and why the result is not I expect. Please, help me.Thanks in advance!

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function largestOfFour(arr) { //loop every inside array in the outside array.
      var data = []; //storing the output array
      for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
        data[x] = largestOfSingle(arr[x]);
      }
      console.log(data); // the result should be [27,5,39,1000]
    }

    function largestOfSingle(myArr) { //find the largest element in every inside array.
      if (myArr.length == 1)
        return myArr[0];
      if (myArr[0] >= myArr[1])
        return largestOfSingle(myArr.splice(1, 1));
      if (myArr[0] < myArr[1])
        return largestOfSingle(myArr.slice(1, myArr.length));
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="largestOfFour([[13, 27, 18, 26], [4, 5, 1, 3], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);">
  <!--two dimensional array-->
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: It's a typo. You are right in your approach. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use Math.max() this will return the highest value directly. No need to code extra function to do exactly that.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) { //loop every inside array in the outside array.
  var data = []; //storing the output array
  for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    data[x] = Math.max(...arr[x]);
  }
  console.log(data); // the result should be [27,5,39,1000]
}
```

EDIT: Fixing OP solution

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function largestOfFour(arr) { //loop every inside array in the outside array.
      var data = []; //storing the output array
      for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
        data[x] = largestOfSingle(arr[x]);
      }
      console.log(data); // the result should be [27,5,39,1000]
    }

    function largestOfSingle(myArr) { //find the largest element in every inside array.
      if (myArr.length == 1)
        return myArr[0];
      if (myArr[0] >= myArr[1]) {
        myArr.splice(1, 1);
        return largestOfSingle(myArr);
      }
      if (myArr[0] < myArr[1])
        return largestOfSingle(myArr.slice(1, myArr.length));
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="largestOfFour([[ 13, 27, 18, 26], [4, 5, 1, 3], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);">
  <!--two dimensional array-->
</body>
<html>
```

You'll notice that I have changed the way you used splice. The thing about what you were doing is that you used the return value of splice, instead of sending the modified array.

From [splice doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

> Return value An array containing the deleted elements. If only one
>   element is removed, an array of one element is returned. If no
>   elements are removed, an empty array is returned.

Comment: But there is a need to code the extra function (learning experience)

Comment: Ok, that wasn't included in OP. And IMHO, I think that learning to reinvent the wheel is not good learning. People should start learning how to use the tools they have at hand, not spend 99% of their coding time redoing them... I'll update the answer if we get more details on the real task at hand, but again, asking for a solution on SO is not much learning practice.

Comment: They are not asking for a solution, they are asking what is wrong with their solution. A helpful clarification of their issue is ideal in this situation and most of the answers tried grabbing a quick upvote for a trivial problem :)

Comment: Plus, "reinventing the wheel" is exactly how we learn...if I want to learn how [].sort() works, i'll implement a few sorting algorithms, if I want to learn how `Math.max` works, i'll implement a function to find a max in array (and i can learn how arrays work, and variable arguments maybe, and argument spread, and loop iteration, etc). Reinventing the wheel is bad when you're not a beginner :).

Comment: @nem035 You are right, I too went the easy way and simply point a "better" solution... I've took the time to debug OP's solution now. Thanks for your heads up

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies here:

```
if (myArr[0] >= myArr[1])
  return largestOfSingle(myArr.splice(1, 1));
```

Splice returns the *spliced out thing*, not the original array. May do:

```
if (myArr[0] >= myArr[1]){
  myArr.splice(1, 1)
  return largestOfSingle(myArr);
}
```

But in my opinion that can be really simplified with a simple for logic:

```
var max = - Infinity;
for(var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++)
  if(myArr[i] > max) max = myArr[i];
return max;
```

Answer (score 1):

If using recursion is not mandatory, you can do it in few lines too:

```
myArr.sort(function(a, b){return b - a});
myArr.reverse();
return myArr[0];
```

Comment: The default sort comparison function compares values as *strings*, not numbers.

Comment: The OP is clearly a beginner and coding everything from scratch serves quite a useful purpose (rather than using helper methods)

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Return_value) returns the *removed* items, not the modified array. Instead, you need to splice the original array before passing it into the recursive `largestOfSingle()`, like so:

```js
function largestOfSingle(myArr) { //find the largest element in every inside array.
  if (myArr.length == 1)
    return myArr[0];
  if (myArr[0] >= myArr[1])
    myArr.splice(1, 1); // splice first
  return largestOfSingle(myArr); // pass in modified array
  if (myArr[0] < myArr[1])
    return largestOfSingle(myArr.slice(1, myArr.length));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The brute force solution is to iterate manually:

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    var largest = [0,0,0,0]; // an array to hold the final result

    // brute force all arrays
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // iterate through sub arrays
        for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            if(arr[i][j] > largest[i]) {
                // overwrite old stored largest if the subarray is larger        
                largest[i] = arr[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
```

Another solution, if it is allowed to use `Math`

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    return arr.map(function(subArr) {
        return Math.max.apply(null, subArr);
     });
}
```

A third solution if `reduce` can be used

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    return arr.map(function (subArr){
        return subArr.reduce(function (oldLargest, newLargest) {
            return (newLargest > oldLargest) 
                ? newLargest
                : oldLargest;
        }, 0);
    });
}
```

Comment: Comments would be helpful (especially considering OP is a beginner)

Comment: @nem035, you are abusing the downvote  ! you are just downvoting every try to help giving the impression of incorrect answer, when you may just leave a comment!

Comment: Not sure why you'd say so. The problem in the question is trivial and since the OP can't solve it, they are most likely a beginner. This means that adding a quick code snippet that the OP can copy-paste serves no purpose in their understanding of the issue.

Comment: @nem035 I updated it with comments, but the downvote is not the right action to ask for comments!

Comment: A downvote is for low-quality answers. Raw code snippet with no clarification text is a low-quality answer :). I will always fix my downvote if appropriate and be open about it :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply that you have accidentally written `slice` instead of `splice` in this line:

```
    return largestOfSingle(myArr.slice(1, myArr.length));
```

Comment: Nope, using slice is fine here.